# Combine two find commands in one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I currently have the following line:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.xml" -delete && find . -type d -empty -delete
```

But as they are 2 find commands, I suppose I can merge them into one. But I don't want to use `-exec`.

I wan't to use something native in bash, that comes preinstalled with any linux distro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group primaries with the `-o` ("or", as opposed to the implict "and" that `find` applies to its primaries) primary. The parentheses are escaped to avoid shell syntax errors and ensure they are passed as arguments to `find`.

```
find . \( \( -type f  ! -name "*.xml" \) -o \( -type d -empty \) \) -delete
```